# Date not updated (handleDateChange) in React Hooks using material-ui-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-hooks

Below is the functional signup component in React. I have one particular problem with the DatePicker component. It renders correctly on the sign up form. When I click on the submit button, it does not give me the selected date but instead it sends me the initial state of the component. Other states such as fullname, password and email are updated accordingly.

To prove that the date was not updated, I tried putting "null" in the useState() and when I get the result in the database, as expected the date is of a "null" type. How do I update the initial state to the updated state?

```
import React, { useState, useContext, Fragment } from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import { signup } from "./auth-api";
import DatePicker from "./DatePicker";
import Copyright from "./Copyright";
import AuthApi from "../utils/AuthApi";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers"; //Date picker util provider
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns"; // Date util library

// We can use inline-style
const style = {
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  borderRadius: 3,
  border: 0,
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: "0 30px",
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function SignUp() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const joindate = new Date();
  const [fullname, setFullname] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [dateofbirth, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "fullname") {
      setFullname(e.target.value);
    } else if (e.target.name === "username") {
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    } else if (e.target.name === "password") {
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  const authApi = React.useContext(AuthApi);
  const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await signup({
      joindate,
      fullname,
      email,
      password,
      dateofbirth,
    });
    if (res.data.auth) {
      authApi.setAuth(true);
    }
    //console.log(res);
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="fullname"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="fullName"
                label="Full Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={handleOnChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="username"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={handleOnChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                onChange={handleOnChange}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <Fragment>
                  <DatePicker
                    inputVariant="outlined"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="dob"
                    name="dob"
                    disableFuture
                    openTo="year"
                    format="dd-MM-yyyy"
                    label="Date of Birth"
                    views={["year", "month", "date"]}
                    value={dateofbirth}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                  />
                </Fragment>
              </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            style={style}
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={handleSignUp}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/signin" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is the Submit button and the Form. How are those related with BasicDatePicker

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I edited my question to include the whole signup component form code. Can you please review the code? Thank you.

Comment: DatePicker is a custom component, i think you removed it from your code?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Previous code (before edit) was a separate Datepicker function exported to the Signup component but now I combined the Datepicker component directly into the Signup component.

Comment: But DatePicker is imported from `import DatePicker from "./DatePicker";`

Comment: You are right. It works now when I change it to import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers"; Thank you!